# Filling DataGridView from Dataset

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have  a `DataSet` and a `DataGridView`. If I click the first button I want to show data from first table, and If I click the second I want to show data from the second table.

I tried the following

```
if(b==1)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Table1;
}
else if(b==1)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Table2;
}
```

But what I see is an empty `DataGridView` (without the column names).

Answer (score 4):

DataSet add tables in the `Tables` collection and you can access these tables from this by their index or table name.

Create common event for your buttons, create as follow on Form_Load:

```
btn1.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);
btn2.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);
```

and then event method as:

```
void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((sender as Button) == btn1)
            {
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            }
            else if ((sender as Button) == btn2)
            {
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];
            }
        }
```

////

```
if(b==1)
{
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
}
else if(b==2)
{
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];
}
```

e.g.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Table1");
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable("Table2");

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
ds.Tables.Add(dt2);

//Now you can access these as:

if(b==1)
    {
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table1"];
    }
    else if(b==2)
    {
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table2"];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you called databind after assigning the datasource ?

```
dataGridView1.DataBind()
```

Comment: ...think that option is only for web forms as opposed to your winFroms